# Axiomatizations of complete theories

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, peano-arithmetic

This question was motivated by this [recent question by Ricky Demer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55944/computable-completion-of-zfc).

In his paper [$\Pi^0_1$ classes and Boolean combinations of recursively enumerable sets](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=344094), Carl Jockusch showed that there is no completion of Peano Arithmetic which is a Boolean combination of computably enumerable (c.e.) sets. This was generalized to any essentially undecidable theory by James Schmerl in his paper [Undecidable theories and reverse mathematics](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2185445).

Are there similar restrictions on the type of sets which can appear as *axiomatizations* of completions of Peano Arithmetic or other computably axiomatizable and essentially undecidable theories? (Other than the trivial fact that such axiomatizations cannot be c.e.) Specifically, does every computably axiomatizable theory have a completion which is axiomatizable by a co-c.e. set?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Every consistent c.e. theory has a $\Sigma^0_2$ (even low $\Delta^0_2$) completion, and therefore a completion axiomatized by a $\Pi^0_1$ set.

In more detail, given a c.e. theory $T$, one can construct its completion by the following procedure: let $\{\phi_n\mid n\in\omega\}$ be a computable enumeration of all sentences in the language of $T$, and put

$$\psi_n=\begin{cases}\phi_n&\text{if }T+\{\psi_i\mid i<n\}+\phi_n\text{ is consistent,}\\\neg\phi_n&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

The branching condition is $\Pi^0_1$, hence the whole thing can be implemented by an algorithm with an oracle for the halting problem. Thus $S=\{\psi_n\mid n\in\omega\}$ is a $\Delta^0_2$ completion of $T$. This completion can be $\Pi^0_1$-axiomatized using Craig's trick: if $S=\{\phi\mid\exists n\,P(n,\phi)\}$, where $P$ is $\Pi^0_1$, then $S$ is axiomatizable by $\{\underbrace{\phi\land\cdots\land\phi}_{n\text{  times}}\mid P(n,\phi)\}$.

Comment: Can you explain how every $\Sigma^0_2$ theory is axiomatized by a $\Pi^0_1$ set?

Comment: In the same way that every $\Sigma^0_1$ theory is axiomatized by a computable set. I've put it in the answer.