# Core model with $\omega$ Woodin cardinals

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, inner-model-theory

In [KwoM] it is proved that the the core model K exists under the assumption that there is no inner model having a Woodin cardinal and satisfying ZFC. Furthermore, they also mention that the result is the "best possible", in the sense that we cannot weaken this anti-large-cardinal hypothesis without strengthening the remainder of the hypothesis.

From what I understand, using the core model induction (which I must admit I don't know the details of yet), K can be constructed below any finite number of Woodin cardinals. So my question is then whether or not K has been constructed below $\omega$ many Woodins and if so, what the extra hypothesis is? If this is indeed the case, I would greatly appreciate a reference to the given paper.

*[KwoM] Jensen and Steel: "K without the measurable"*

**Edit:** In the introduction to [Schindler and Steel's "The Core Model Induction"](http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/logik/Personen/rds/core_model_induction.pdf), they write that if we assume that there is no proper class model with $n+1$ Woodins and over every set there is a proper class model with $n$ Woodins, then $K$ exists (in the sense of the above [KwoM]).

Can this be extended to: if there is no proper class model with $\omega$ Woodins and over every set there is a proper class model with $n$ Woodins, for every $n<\omega$, then $K$ exists?

Comment: There is a construction of inner model for assumptions up to Woodin cardinal which is a limit of strong cardinals (due to Neeman). The issue is that once there is a Woodin cardinal, those inner models can be changed by forcing (they are no longer generic absolute).

Comment: Thanks for the comment Yair. It seems that we can get around this absoluteness issue by considering relative premice, from what I can tell by Andrés' answer to the following MO question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/153745/latest-stand-of-core-model-theory. He mentions that one of these extra assumptions we could use is that V is closed under sharps. I'm just interested in how exactly the theorem is stated, if other assumptions is needed as well.

Comment: In the introduction to Schindler and Steel's "The Core Model Induction", they write that if we assume that there is no proper class model with $n+1$ Woodins and over every set there is a proper class model with $n$ Woodins, then $K$ exists (in the sense of the above [KwoM]).

Can this be extended to: if there is no proper class model with $\omega$ Woodins and over every set there is a proper class model with $n$ Woodins, for every $n<\omega$, then $K$ exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dan, the answer is "no." You might be in a situation where K<sup>c</sup> is a mouse (i.e., its ctble. substructures are ω<sub>1</sub>+1 iterable), but K<sup>c</sup> is not fully iterable. E.g. it could be that K<sup>c</sup> has M<sub>2</sub><sup>F,#</sup>, where F is the operator simultaneously closing under all M<sub>n</sub><sup>#</sup>, n<ω, but for some θ, V = L<sup>F</sup>(V<sub>θ</sub>) (same F, V could even be an extender model): the Q-structures needed to fully iterate M<sub>2</sub><sup>F,#</sup> would be given by the M<sub>1</sub><sup>F,#</sup> operator which is not available thruout the universe. If K<sup>c</sup> is not fully iterable, one can't use it to isolate K, and in such a situation usually there is no inner model which has enough of the relevant properties that it might be called "the core model." See e.g. the first two pages of 
 https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/rds/K.pdf  for a list of such properties.
 (There are exceptions to this, though, see e.g.  https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/rds/CMPW.pdf  and also  https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/rds/RalfGrigor_version_Sept11_2017.pdf .)

Comment: Thanks Ralf! Just to see if I get the argument: if we consider the operator $G:=M_1^{F,\sharp}$ and assume $K^c$ reaches $M_1^{G,\sharp}$ then to show that $M_1^{G,\sharp}$ is fully iterable we need to be able to build $L^G(\mathcal M(\mathcal T))$ in $V$ to be able to form the necessary $\mathcal Q$-structures, but we can arrange that $V$ isn't closed under $G$. So this shows that we can't even get $K$ if both $V$ is closed under $F$ and $M_2^{F,\sharp}$ exists, which is possible even with the requirement that there be no inner model with $\omega$ Woodins. Is this correctly understood?

Comment: Yep, that's the thing :)