# What does $L(A,\mathbb{R})$ mean?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, inner-model-theory, inner-models

I many papers by Woodin, and on some answers here on MathOverflow (like [the first answer of this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46907/completion-of-zfc)), I see the expression "$L(A,\mathbb{R})$" being used, but I have never seen it defined. I first assumed it meant "$L(A\cup\mathbb{R})$" but on the answer I linked it is precised that $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ so clearly that's not it as it would be $L(\mathbb{R})$ whatever $A$ is. A friend of mine suggested it might rather be $L(\{A,\mathbb{R}\})$ which seems likely (as $A$ might just be not constructible from the reals) but I would like a confirmation by someone who knows.

So, what does it mean?

Comment: I'd understand this to mean the smallest transitive proper class model of ZF that contains all the reals and $A$ as elements. More explicitly, start with $\omega\cup\mathbb P(\omega)\cup\{A\}$ (where I assume $A\subseteq\mathbb P(\omega)$), and iterate "definable power set" through all the ordinals (just as in the definition of $L$).

Comment: Defining it as $L(\{A,\mathbb{R}\})$ would be exactly starting with (the transitive closure of) what you just said, I think that's it, but I haven't found any explicit statement of this

Comment: Yes, that's it.