# Does $V = \textit{Ultimate }L$ imply GCH?

Tags: set-theory, continuum-hypothesis, constructibility, gch

In his Midrasha Mathematicae lectures ("In Search of Ultimate $L$", BSL 23 [2017]: 1–109), Woodin notes that $V = \textit{Ultimate }L$ implies $\textrm{CH}$ (Theorem 7.26, p.103). Is it known whether $V = \textit{Ultimate }L$ implies $\textrm{GCH}$?

Comment: For Woodin's paper: https://doi.org/10.1017/bsl.2016.34

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In his slide [Absolutely ordinal definable sets](http://logic.berkeley.edu/logic@UCB/Steel_logic@UCB.pdf) John Steel writes:

> At the same time, one hopes that V = ultimate L will yield a detailed ﬁne structure theory for V, removing the incompleteness that large cardinal hypotheses by themselves can never remove. It is known that V = ultimate L implies the CH, and many instances of the GCH. Whether it implies the full GCH is a crucial open problem

Answer (score 9):

During this year's conferene on inner model theory in Münster, Gabriel Goldberg proved that the so-called *Ultrapower Axiom* implies that $\mathrm{GCH}$ holds above a supercompact cardinal (and since then lowered the bound to a strongly compact cardinal). It seems very likely (it might even be known) that $\mathrm{Ultimate } \ L$ satisfies this requirement. Hence, given enough large cardinals, it will satisfy $\mathrm{GCH}$ at least on a tail end.

For more information, see [G. Goldberg. Strong Compactness and the Ultrapower Axiom](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.03586.pdf).